# What is the command that cause the SSD hard disc to return read error (LBA error)

Tags: ssd, nvme

Currently I need to build an automated to test that check how the system handle LBA-error. Is there any command via any way that make SSD hard disc to return read-error. According to [NVMe protocol](http://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVM_Express_1_2_Gold_20141209.pdf) - **6.15 Write Uncorrectable command** There should be such command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was completely new with nvme. So, the nvme-cli is an interface that hard driver vendors supposed to support. But in some modules the commands don't work. So don't give up! Try another hard driver.

```
nvme write-uncor /dev/nvme2n1 -s 0 -c 5 -n 1
```

The device **-s** and **-c** is clear (check the help) bun the **-n**, namespace-id are given in the device name, nvme2**n1** means that **-n** is **1**.

Answer (score 0):

There's `nvme-write-uncor` command in `nvme-cli`

```
nvme-write-uncor - Send an NVMe write uncorrectable command, return results
```

According to NVMe protocol:

```
When the specified logical block(s) are read after this operation, a failure
is returned with Unrecovered Read Error status.
```

So, to get read-error you need to read formerly corrupted blocks.

Project page: https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli

Comment: The parameter of the command are **[--start-block=<slba> | -s <slba>]                         [--block-count=<nlb> | -c <nlb>] [--namespace-id=<nsid> | -n <nsid>]**. How can I extract them? And are they optional? because I always receive **NVME IO command error:INVALID_FIELD(2)** error. I fail to find examples. Thank for help.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `/dev/nvme*` device?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried other command like **error-log** and they worked.

Comment: I've never used NVMe, but in specification they say that there is something called _namespace_ on disk. Here's an excerpt of point 6.1: `[...]specifying an inactive namespace ID in a command that uses the namespace ID shall cause the controller to abort the command with status Invalid Field in Command`. Looks like this is your error. Try using `nvme-list-ns` to get a list of namespace IDs, and specify it by using `-n` to `nvme-write-uncor`. OR use `/dev/nvme0n*` device, because it seems that it's another way to access a namespace.